# nginx file is consuming hard drive

Tags: nginx

Why does the file /usr/local/nginx/on take up so much hard drive space on my web server? What can i do to reduce it?

Answer (score 2):

Probably, in your nginx.conf situated something like this: `error_log on;`

Answer (score 1):

You might have "access_log on" defined in your nginx config file. Remove it from your config file if you dont want that file to be created.